# SSH/SSH2 : Is there a way to find out when the server is ready for receiving input?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

When using some programming language (in my case Java w/ Jsch) or SSH client (i.e. SecureCRT), I am able to interact with the remote system terminal as if I was really on that system.  How does the client know when the server is ready for input.
As an example, consider the quintessential greeting program called "Greeting"...

```
>>./Greeting
>>Please Enter You Name:
>>Bob
>>Hello Bob!
```

My question is, after the user submits "Bob" by pressing the return key on the client machine,  the remote machine will take some time to execute, form and return the greeting string, during which SecureCRT seems to know that the server is not accepting any input (it won't show the flashing input cursor).  How does it know this?  Is there some message the server sends indicating it is ready to receive input again?

Also, is there a way to detect this using Jsch?

Comment: It is not fundamentally different than if run in a terminal locally without SSH.

Comment: It sounds like you want something like [expect4j](http://nikunjp.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/remote-ssh-using-jsch-with-expect4j/).